Why does dividing the nth Fibonacci sequence by the hypotenuse of a right triangle made from the sequence itself approach a constant?
Fn is the nth value of the Fibonacci Sequence given in the left column. I use the Fibonacci sequence as the legs of a right triangle and find the length of the hypotenuse of this right triangle for the right column. I divide the left and right columns and get this ratio approaching a constant $\approx 0.525731112...$ Why does this happen? Is there anything profound here or is it just the property related to the Golden ratio?


@DietrichBurde that reasoning works only if $F_n$ converges, which it doesn't. See my answer.

It's also interesting to note that the second column is equal to $\sqrt{F_{2n+1}}$, though this doesn't really help us solve the problem.

@CheerfulParsnip Yes, sorry, I was not thinking about it.

As Dietrich Burde states, the formula you want the limit of is $$\frac{F_n}{\sqrt{F_n^2+F_{n+1}^2}}.$$ His reasoning would be valid if the sequence $F_n$ converged because in that case $F_{n+1}\approx F_n$.
Instead use that $F_{n+1} \approx \phi F_n$ where $\phi$ is the golden ratio. Then the formula becomes
$$\frac{F_n}{\sqrt{F_n^2+(\phi F_n)^2}}.$$
This simplifies to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\phi^2}}\approx 0.525731112.$

And this can of course be made fully rigorous by first dividing the numerator and denominator by $F_n$ then taking the limit.

Using the Golden ratio limit:
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}\rightarrow\phi$
We can square both sides and get $F_{n+1}^{2} = \phi^{2}F_{n}^{2}$
The ratio that I'm getting following the table is $\frac{F_{n}}{\sqrt{F_{n}^{2}+F_{n+1}^{2}}}$. We substitute for $F_{n+1}^{2}$ from the step above and get $\frac{F_{n}}{\sqrt{F_{n}^{2}+\phi^{2}F_{n}^{2}}}$.
We factor out $F_{n}$ and divide out the factor $F_{n}$ and get the final answer
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\phi^{2}}} \approx 0.525731112...$
